# Hive : getting parseexception in simple create external table query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I have set up hive on mac. While executing simple create external table query. I am  getting below stack trace :

```
        hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE weatherext ( wban INT, date STRING)
        > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
        > FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
        > LOCATION ‘ /hive/data/weatherext’;
```

> NoViableAltException(80@[]) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeOrPKOrFK(HiveParser.java:33341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeOrPKOrFKList(HiveParser.java:29513)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:6175)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:3808)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:2382)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1333)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:77)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:70)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:468)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1316)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1456)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1236)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1226)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>       FAILED: ParseException line 1:45 cannot recognize input near 'date' 'STRING' ')' in column name or primary key or foreign key.

I am able to run same query successfully on ubuntu.
Is it mandatory to surround coulmn names with ` in hive2?

Comment: which line is exactly generating this exception?

Comment: @Mandy8055 - "ParseException line 1:45"

Answer (score 3):

1. `date` is a reserved word and should be qualified.
2. You are using the wrong qualifiers. You should use `'` and not `‘` or `’`.
3. You have space in the beginning of your location `/hive/data...`

---

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE weatherext (wban INT, `date` STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/hive/data/weatherext';
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked. Can you please suggest me some good hive tutorial , book . I am absolute beginner.